# Submit Button Don't work HTML

Tags: html

At Click "Login", Nothing, Don't Procces The Form, Can Help me?

Code:

```
        <form method="POST" action="" id="login">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
            <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group"> 
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
            <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" form="login" class="btn btn-success btn-submit" value="Login">
        </div>
    </form>
```

what is Wrong? Can Help Me?
**uPDATE** Code: https://hastebin.com/wemerigodu.scala

Comment: What you what on "Login" button click?

Comment: When I click, I should load the page, but when I click, the button does not work, I need to know when I'm wrong

Comment: For That you have to specify action in form.

Comment: you have to enter the target url in `action="" ` tag

Answer (score 3):

When you are making the form, you have typed:
`<form method="POST" action="" id="login>"`
To make the form working type the file name that contains the code to login for example:

```
<form method="POST" action="login_verify.php" id="login">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group"> 
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
        <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" form="login" class="btn btn-success btn-submit" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: oh, don't work :( is problem of my assets or anything?

Comment: What is the file name that contains the code for the login (PHP)

Comment: the same page, (login.php), the all code of login.php (form): https://hastebin.com/julasuxeka.xml

Comment: Try <form method="POST" action="login.php" id="login">

Comment: i tested with a normal form, and don't work, is my assets sure

Comment: I think the fault is in the php code, but I'm not sure (still a student)

Comment: I had once the same fault, the reason was within my php code. Can't remember what was wrong.

Comment: I did not meant that you need to remove your php code, there is a error in your php code, I will take a look at your php code that you sended.

Comment: LOL, now works, i removed the js files of end, and now works, thanks for reply

Comment: No problem, glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

A button located outside a form (but still a part of the form).

And you have a page in action attribute that receives the submitted field's value.

```html
<form action="Your_Handle_Page" method="get" id="form1">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I Used This, And Don't Work

Answer (score 1):

you haven't specify action on form submit you need to write redirect url in form action element as below.

```
<form method="POST" action="xyz.html" id="login">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group"> 
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">
        <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" required>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <input type="submit" form="login" class="btn btn-success btn-submit" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
```